# cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

if i wanna use indexing i got a error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Robson1608\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Robson1608\Desktop\Nowy folder\run.py", line 79, in on_message
await cmds.get(invoke).ex(args, message, client, invoke)
File "C:\Users\Robson1608\Desktop\Nowy folder\commands\cmd_play.py", line 7, in ex
await Music().play(client, message, message.author.voice.voice_channel, link)
File "C:\Users\Robson1608\Desktop\Nowy folder\core\discordmusic.py", line 11, in play
self.players[int(message.server.id)] = await voice.create_ytdl_player(link, use_avconv=False)
IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

Code here:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.players = []
async def play(self, client, message, channel, link):
    voice = await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    voice.encoder_options(sample_rate=48000, channels=2)
    self.players[int(message.server.id)] = await voice.create_ytdl_player(link, use_avconv=False)
    self.players[int(message.server.id)].start()
def pause(self, message):
    self.players[int(message.server.id)].pause()
```

Any idea to resolve this problem? ;v I dont know what is problem i search google but dont see any solution

Comment: Your id is too big for the type int. That generates an overflow. What type is message.server.id? If you want to google, you need to look for "IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer". There are some topics about that out there.

Comment: I would suggest using a dictionary instead of a list. It's faster and it's far easier to track your players using their id instead of using indexes.

Comment: @Schorsch its <class 'str'> but its only number

Comment: @Nathan But how to use?

Comment: @Famous to init `self.players = {}` and then every time you add a player you do `self.players[message.server.id]  = player`. To retrieve a specific player you do `self.players[message.server.id]`

Comment: @Nathan def play work but now i got error with pause:

Comment: File "C:\Users\Robson1608\Desktop\Nowy folder\core\discordmusic.py", line 20, in pause
    self.players[message.server.id].pause()
KeyError: '326912032483835904'

Comment: @Nathan a lookup in a dictionary isn't faster than a lookup in an array. Array lookup works in constant time, dictionary lookup works in logarithmic time. But apart from that, a dictionary would be the better container in this case.

Comment: @Famous, did you tried to print the id's of your messages? Your problem is discribed here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/keyerror-python  You try to access an element by a key which isn't there.

Comment: Yes i try to print and in def play print class and id but on pause i got a key error ;v

Comment: @Schorsch I didn't know that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nathan in an array, you access through index. The calculation of the resulting address is constant because you have the starting address, the size of one element and the position, so start + size_element * position is your address. A dictionary is normally a tree structure, often a binary tree, you gro from the root and decide by < or > operator  which child tree to go untill you reach the element you want. Maybe you meant a hash table, which can have constant times for lookup if you implement it right and your hash function is good enough.

Comment: @Schorsch that's really interesting. I didn't mean a  lookup table, I was just wrong :).